# SELECT COUNT(*) for unique pairs of IDs

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following, named `matches`:

```
match_id ( AUTO INCREMENT )
user_id ( INT 11 )
opponent_id ( INT 11 )
date ( TIMESTAMP )
```

What I have to do is to `SELECT` the count of the rows where `user_id` and `opponent_id` are a **unique pair**. The goal is to see the count of total matches started between different users.

So if we have:

```
user_id = 10 and opponent_id = 11
user_id = 20 and opponent_id = 22
user_id = 10 and opponent_id = 11
user_id = 11 and opponent_id = 10
```

The result of the query should be 2.

In fact we only have 2 matches that have been started by a couple of different users. Match 1 - 3 - 4 are the same matches, because played by the same couple of user IDs.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have done similar queries but never on *pairs* of IDs, always on a single ID.

Answer (score 3):

FancyPants answer is correct, but I prefer to use DISTINCT when no aggregate function is used:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
  LEAST(user_id, opponent_id), 
  GREATEST(user_id, opponent_id)
)
FROM yourtable;
```

is sufficient.

Comment: Oh my, yes...that's of course more elegant. Haven't had enough coffee yet :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nr_of_matches FROM (
SELECT 
LEAST(user_id, opponent_id) AS pl1, 
GREATEST(user_id, opponent_id) AS pl2
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY pl1, pl2
) sq
```

- see it working in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed67/5/0)

Comment: @downvoter It may not be the most elegant, but it's not wrong! And the not so elegant answers often still help others understand how the elegant one works.